# dotnet core 1.1(sdk 1.0.1)'s asp.net core package not compatible

Tags: asp.net-core

I installed dotnet core 1.1 and visual studio 2017 with '.NET Core cross-platform development'. After that, uninstalled previous dotnet sdk(preview etc).

when I make new project 'ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core), I show this error message(cli - dotnet restore too)

> Error      Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides 1.1.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides 1.1.1 supports:
>     - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
>     - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)

thank for your help...

Comment: do u use an prerelease nuget feed on https://dotnet.myget.org ? Did u try to remove all package in %UserProfile%/.nuget/packages ?

Comment: @aguafrommars - thanks a lot. you are my hero.

Comment: What di u do ? Posting an answer may help people